# WPF DataBinding of a label

Tags: c#, wpf

im now trying for hours to get the databinding run.
But whatever im trying nothing works.
After a few thousend examples and retries (feels like a ffew thousand) i decided to make a new thread for my problem.

I have a window where you can select a woker.
On these window there are a UserControl which shows the details of the selected worker.
It would be nice to have all labels / textboxes / comboboxes filled automatically in case the selected worker changed.

For that the UserControl has a Property "ShownWorker" which contains the selected worker.

Worker Class:

```
    public class Worker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private string id;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public Worker() 
    { 

    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
        private Worker shownWorker;
    public Worker ShownWorker
    {
        get
        {
            return shownWorker;
        }
        set
        {
            shownWorker = value;
        }
    }

    public WorkerDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = shownWorker;
    }
```

Label on the UserControl:

```
<Label Height="28" Margin="129,6,6,0" Name="labelWorkerID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding ID, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"></Label>
```

And im setting the ShownWorker like that:

```
private void dataGridAvaibleWorker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridAvaibleWorker.SelectedItem is Worker)
        {
            var selectedWorker= (Worker)dataGridAvaibleWorker.SelectedItem;
            WorkerDetails.ShownWorker = selectedWorker;
        }
    }
```

But nothing happens. Whats wrong?
I dont get it.

Comment: You are setting the `ShownWorker` property, but you are not raising an `PropertyChanged` events for that property - the UI doesn't know that the `ShownWorker` value has changed. Property changed events only notify the UI that a property has changed, they don't know about children/parent properties, you have to implement property changed events for all properties that you want the UI to react to.

Comment: Also another issue is that you are setting the `ShownWorker` property to another object reference - references to references won't be affected when you change the former: you can't expect that `DataContext` will point to another object when you change a reference that both `DataContext` and `ShownWorker` are pointing to

Comment: This is because of the way references work - I'll explain in an answer

Comment: Even in case im implementing the PropertyChange event in the UserControl and raise a PropertyChange event in the setter of the ShownWorker is doesent work.

Comment: Youre right. In case im setting the dataContext again in the setter of the ShownWorker it works but that dosent look fine. Is there an elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the property change notification, you have another issue:

These two properties:

```
ShownWorker
DataContext
```

Are pointing to the same reference when the form opens - e.g.

```
Worker someWorker = new Worker();
ShownWorker = someWorker;
DataContext = ShownWorker;
```

Changing `ShownWorker` here does not affect `DataContext`

```
ShownWorker = new Worker();
```

`DataContext` at this point still references the original worker - when you do this assignment `DataContext = ShownWorker`, `DataContext` references the worker you instantiated in the first of the three lines, it does not refer to the instance that `ShownWorker` is pointing to

To try and explain it a bit better:

```
// I'll stick some 'tags' on to shown how the instances will be referenced
Worker someWorker = new Worker(); // someWorker = "Instance1"
ShownWorker = someWorker;         // ShownWorker points to "Instance1"
DataContext = ShownWorker;        // DataContext points to "Instance1"

ShownWorker = new Worker();       // ShownWorker now points to "Instance2"
                                  // DataContext still points to "Instance1"
```

You need to set `DataContext` not `ShownWorker` and raise a property changed event for `DataContext`

A better way to do this is to use an MVVM approach e.g.

```
public class WorkerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Put standard INPC implementation here
    public event PropertyChanged.... etc

    private Worker shownWorker;
    public Worker ShownWorker
    {
        get
        {
            return shownWorker;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value == shownWorker) return; // Don't do anything if the value didn't change
            shownWorker = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ShownWorker");
        }
    }

    public WorkerViewModel() 
    {
        ShownWorker = // Get/create the worker etc
    }
}
```

Now you have a VM you can set the `DataContext` to:

```
public WorkerViewModel WorkerViewModel { get; private set; }

public WorkerDetails()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WorkerViewModel = new WorkerViewModel();
    this.DataContext = WorkerViewModel;
}
```

And updates can be done to the VM instead:

```
WorkerViewModel.ShownWorker = someWorker;
```

Make sure you set your bindings in the XAML

```
<UserControl>
    <SomeControl DataContext="{Binding ShownWorker}" />
</UserControl>
```

Instead of rolling your own MVVM stuff - I'd suggest looking at some popular MVVM frameworks as they can make working with WPF/Silverlight a breeze.

My personal fave is Caliburn Micro but there are plenty out there (MVVMLight, Prism, etc)